# How can I represent an infinite loop in a sequence diagram?

Tags: design-patterns, computer-science, sequence-diagram

Can I say the number of iterations is (1..*)? or put a condition as [true]? How do I do this?
This is to let a user attempt to login an infinite number of times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to represent a call being made in a loop in a sequence diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526410/how-to-represent-a-call-being-made-in-a-loop-in-a-sequence-diagram)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you want to exit when the user has successfully logged in.
[image]

See [here](https://zenuml.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/Doc/pages/1384185859/How+can+I+represent+an+infinite+loop+in+a+sequence+diagram) for how the diagram is generated.